# More than 1 Year Date Query

Tags: wp-query

Is it possible to use multiple years with a date query like this -

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => array( 2016, 2017 )
        ),
    ),
);


$posts = new WP_Query(array( $args ) );
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
'year'  => array( 2016, 2017 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `before` and `after`, see [date arguments](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters).

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'date_query'     => array(
        array(
            'after'  => 'December 31st, 2015', // i.e., 2016+.
            'before' => 'January 1st, 2018', // i.e., before 2018.
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

---

Based on an [article](https://alex.blog/2013/08/27/date-queries-in-wordpress-3-point-7/) written by one of the date query committers, it looks like you can use `AND` `OR` logic date queries too. So you can also do this.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => '-1',
    'date_query'      => array(
        'relation'    => 'OR',
        array( 'year' => 2016 ),
        array( 'year' => 2017 ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

---

All possible arguments according to that author.

```
'date_query' => array(
    'column' => 'optional, column to query against, default is post_date',
    'compare' => 'optional, see WP_Date_Query::get_compare()',
    'relation' => 'optional, OR or AND, how the sub-arrays should be compared, default is AND',
    array(
        'column' => 'see above',
        'compare' => 'see above',
        'after' => 'string or array, see WP_Date_Query::build_mysql_datetime()',
        'before' => 'string or array, see WP_Date_Query::build_mysql_datetime()',
        'inclusive' => 'boolean, for after/before, whether exact value should be matched or not',
        'year' => '4 digit int',
        'month' => 'int, 1-12',
        'week' => 'int, 0-53',
        'day' => 'int, 1-31',
        'hour' => 'int, 0-23',
        'minute' => 'int, 0-60',
        'second' => 'int, 0-60',
    ),
    array(
        ...
    ),
    ..
),
```

Comment: Ok so you can't use a array of specific years?

Comment: @Dev It looks like you can, yes. I just updated my answer for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I use `After` and `Before` to show the most popular post in the period between two years.

Work's fine!

```
$current_year = get_the_date('Y'); //Get Current Year of the Page - Header Page
$last_year = (get_the_date('Y') - 2) //2 is the year for calculated the period ;    
$args = array(
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'posts_per_page'  => 6,
          'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
          'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
          'order' => 'RAND',
          'date_query'     => array(
            array(
                'after'  => $last_year,
                'before' => $current_year,
            ),
          ),
          'post_status'  => 'publish'
        );
$myposts = new WP_Query( $args );
```